# Laravel - what type of relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am just trying to learn Laravel and it's my first question here, so I hope I will describe it right.

I have a 3 models PROFILE, CUSTOMER and VEHICLE (and also USER)

user have a profile, every profile can have multiple customers and every customer can have multiple vehicles.
I want to make an index page where logged user and it's profile show all vehicles for all their customers.
When i try this:

```
auth()->user()->profile->customers
```

it get me all the customers, thats OK, but I want to continue and make something like this

```
auth()->user()->profile->customers->vehicles
```

or maybe

```
auth()->user()->profile->vehicles
```

I thought "hasManyThrough" will help me but not

I want to get a list of all the vehicles for all customers. But it doesn't work.

thank you very much for any help

**USER MODEL**

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

**PROFILE MODEL**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function customers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Customer');

}

public function vehicles(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Vehicle', 'App\Customer'); //this is probably wrong
}
```

**CUSTOMER MODEL**

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
}

public function vehicles() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicle');
}

public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

**VEHICLE MODEL**

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

PROFILE table has user_id,
CUSTOMER table has profile_id,
VEHICLES table has customer_id

Comment: your relationships look fine, what is the error you are getting? `auth()->user()->profile->vehicles` should work. note that `auth()->user()->profile->customers->vehicles` will not work, you would need to specify for which customer you want to fetch the vehicles, like `auth()->user()->profile->customers->first()->vehicles`.

Comment: Ou I don't understand it. Now the 
auth()->user()->profile->vehicles is working
but I dont know why, I was trying to many things and lost what changed cause last couple of hours i was trying many combinations  and also via tinker and it was still getting me "null"
So perfect, I just leard to use hasManyThrough relationship cause I thought that was the problem.

i also thought
auth()->user()->profile->customers->vehicles
will make some kind of intersection 

anyway thank you very much